# Прочитать выбранный файл из ComboBox. C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть `void ReadFile(string path)`, А так же есть код, который добавляет txt-файлы в `combobox`:

```
            string path = Application.StartupPath;
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            var files = new List<string>();

            foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.txt"))
            {
                files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file.FullName));
            }
            foreach (string str in files)
            {
                combobox.Items.Add(str);
            }
```

Как сделать, чтобы выбранный файл в `combobox` можно было указать как `path` для `ReadFile`?

Пробовал так, но ничего не получилось:

```
 ReadFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + combobox.SelectedText);
```

Comment: WinForms или WPF ?

Comment: WinForms, забыл добавить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблон чтения файла, имя которого выбрано в ComboBox.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                .Select(x => $"file_{x}.txt")
                .ToArray());
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()));
            MessageBox.Show(text);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рекомендации

Для формирования путей используйте `Path.Combine()`. Это очень упрощает жизнь и при разработке кроссплатформенных приложений на базе .Net Core.

Answer (score 1):

Например так

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Application.StartupPath;
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        //загружаем массив FileInfo в комбобокс
        _comboBox.Items.AddRange(dir.GetFiles("*.txt"));
        //отображаем в комбобоксе только название файла
        _comboBox.DisplayMember = nameof(FileInfo.Name);
        //если были загружены txt файлы подписываемся на событие выбора
        if (_comboBox.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            _comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }

    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //получаем полный путь к файлу
        var file = (_comboBox.SelectedItem as FileInfo).FullName;
        //отображаем содержимое файла в RichTextBox
        _richTextBox.LoadFile(file, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    }
}
```